# Speed up running process in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, build, android-studio

Everytime I run my project in Android Studio, it is compiled, then there is the Gradle build, and then it makes me choose the emulator. Is there a way to speed things up?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the solution at this link :

https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

It worked for me so it worth to try.

An other solution :
In Android Studio preferences > Compiler > Gradle > check "Compile independent modules in parallel" and put some VM Options.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your build configuration, you can choose when to do when you run your project, and what device to use.

To edit a build config select Edit Configuations from the drop down next to the run button in the toolbar. You can also specify an activity to run there too, and change the defaults.

Comment: ok thanks, that saves the choice of the emulator. But is there a way to compile automatically, just like in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, I've only really used Android Studio. How do you mean compile automatically?

Comment: When the project is saved, it is built also. I guess that could save a lot of time?

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm not sure if it's able to do that or not. If not there might be a plugin to do that. Maybe somebody else will know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [Android Studio update](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio030released) which increase the gradle manipulations optimization.
It "went down from two and a half minutes to fourteen seconds" any import, sync, etc..

The link explain how to implement the functionnality.

If you have a gradle version error here is the solution:
[Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6)

Hope it helped :)