# Android Studio new installation and new project fails

Tags: android, ide

I just installed Android Studio 0.3.6 and it fails to create a new project with all default options.  The error message is:

Cause: unexpected end of block data

[image]

I don't have any projects, so there is no way to even access the Help menu. How do I fix this so I can start the IDE?

I'm adding the error log from idea.log

```
2013-11-22 22:47:01,686 [  86851]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $WORKSPACE_FILE$ file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,699 [  86864]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.PsiAwareFileEditorManagerImpl initialized in 12 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,699 [  86864]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ui.EditorNotifications initialized in 12 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,700 [  86865]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/encodings.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,709 [  86874]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/modules.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,744 [  86909]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/vcs.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,747 [  86912]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesViewManager initialized in 21 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,775 [  86940]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl initialized in 53 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,778 [  86943]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.VcsDirtyScopeManagerImpl initialized in 56 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,790 [  86955]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners initialized in 75 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,807 [  86972]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.CtrlMouseHandler initialized in 12 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,832 [  86997]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.packaging.impl.artifacts.ArtifactManagerImpl initialized in 11 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,833 [  86998]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/compiler.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,838 [  87003]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,839 [  87004]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,877 [  87042]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.framework.detection.impl.FrameworkDetectionManager initialized in 13 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,900 [  87065]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.xdebugger.impl.XDebuggerManagerImpl initialized in 22 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,915 [  87080]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dynamic.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,973 [  87138]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - org.jetbrains.idea.maven.tasks.MavenTasksManager initialized in 54 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:01,976 [  87141]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - org.jetbrains.idea.maven.navigator.MavenProjectsNavigator initialized in 57 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,034 [  87199]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.designer.DesignerToolWindowManager initialized in 53 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,064 [  87229]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.designer.palette.PaletteToolWindowManager initialized in 30 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,080 [  87245]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/vcs.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,116 [  87281]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - git4idea.repo.GitRepositoryManager initialized in 51 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,152 [  87317]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - org.zmlx.hg4idea.HgRepositoryWatcher initialized in 30 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,157 [  87322]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 138 project components initialized in 713 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,157 [  87322]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,162 [  87327]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gradle.xml file is null 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,181 [  87346]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,181 [  87346]   INFO - i.vcs.changes.ChangeListWorker - default list not found when copy in original object too 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,258 [  87423]   INFO - napi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSession - [CR-IC-2706] [] 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,273 [  87438]   INFO - napi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSession - [CR-IC-2706] [] 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,307 [  87472]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,312 [  87477]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32 
2013-11-22 22:47:02,314 [  87479]   INFO - dle.util.AndroidGradleSettings - Found Android SDK home at 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/Android Studio/sdk' (from local.properties file) 
2013-11-22 22:47:09,282 [  94447]   INFO - ject.ProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'C:\Users\Marcin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:167)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:657)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:152)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:108)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(ActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1370)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:150)
    ... 13 more
2013-11-22 22:47:09,284 [  94449]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: unexpected end of block data 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: unexpected end of block data
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:657)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: unexpected end of block data
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:657)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)


2013-11-22 22:47:09,285 [  94450]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter - com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: unexpected end of block data
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:274)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:657)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)


2013-11-22 22:47:09,285 [  94450]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectImporter - Cause: unexpected end of block data

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be the version of gradle used to compile. ThePatio gives a helpful response in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6) SO question.

> I am not sure if this will help you but here is what fixed it for me:
>
> Open up this file in your project:
>
> /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>
> Edit the distributionUrl line and set it too:
>
> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
>
> Rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I was getting the SO's issue when I tried creating a new Gradle Android project after upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 13.