# Android Studio 0.4: Could not find method jniDir()

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

When updating to Android Studio 0.4, which uses the android gradle plugin 0.7.0 and gradle 1.9, following error occurs:

> org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method jniDir() ...

which refers to the follwing lines in my build.gradle:

```
 tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
   pkgTask.jniDir new File(projectDir, 'native-libs')
 }
```

P.S.: These answers fixed all other upgrade issues for me:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496969/1137547
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461162/1137547

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*jniDir()* has been replaced by *jniFolders()*. You can set it like this:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'native-libs'))
}
```

I found this solution in this [discussion](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/BN8mx2pGk9h)

Comment: What's the point of asking a question when you have the answer for it in the moment of asking?

Comment: @soulreaver so other people can use it?! Why would SO offer the option to "Answer your own question" otherwise?