# How to define Gradle version to use inside build.gradle?

Tags: android, build, gradle, version

[Android new build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) requires Gradle 1.10+ version. How to configure that inside `build.gradle` ?

I am aware that there is some wrapper configuration in other files, but I would like to make it more visible, as my goal is to prevent potential errors (time lost by team mates) in the future.

Compare to maven `pom.xml`

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

ref [Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot configure the Gradle version in `build.gradle`. Instead, you'll have to configure the Gradle wrapper as explained in the link you gave. For additional information see the *Gradle Wrapper* chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#wrapper_pluginl).

Configuring the Gradle Wrapper does not *check* that the correct Gradle version is used as in the POM snippet above, but it *bootstraps* the correct Gradle version for everyone that runs Gradle via the Gradle Wrapper (which includes the IDE), which is much more powerful. It would be easy to additionally check for the correct Gradle version in `build.gradle` (e.g. `assert gradle.gradleVersion == "1.10"`), but typically this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to write something like `assert gradle.gradleVersion >= "1.10"` within `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Not easily. You'd have to parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the Peter who is likely working for GradleWare and is authoritative source.

Direct answer to the question is

```
assert gradle.gradleVersion >= "1.10" // android plugin 0.9 requires Gradle 1.10, 1.11
```

Updating [Nodeclipse/Enide build.gradle template for classic Android project](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle)

Comment: Comparing version number strings with `>=` won't give the correct result.

Comment: It worked however with 1.10 and 1.10; but yes, generally it it not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. You can configure the gradle version in a wrapper task

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
   gradleVersion = '1.4'
}
```

This assures You that (when using wrapper) all users will have the same version. There's no need for version checking, parsing and other..