# Showing Gradle error because versions are different?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have created an project in Android Studio 1.2.1.1 now i opened the same project in Android Studio 1.3.2. Now i am getting Gradle error because Gradle versions are different. Is there a way where i can convert old gradle to new gradle?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460349/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-6?rq=1

Comment: POst your gradle-plugin and gradle version. Also the exact error message.