# Update Android Studio Gradle plugin to last version

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm new to Android developpement and I tried to install the Facebook SDK in my Android Studio project.

Then, I have a bug in build.gradle :

```
Error:(111, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.
```

So I searched for a solution and I found this on the stack:

> This is a known issue , which is fixed by updating gradle to :

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
}
```

So I tried this but then I got the error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/home/roman/Documents/softs/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.2/gradle-1.1.2.pom
file:/home/roman/Documents/softs/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.1.2/gradle-1.1.2.jar
Required by:
Yoki:facebook:unspecified
```

So I moved into the specified directory and then there is only this:

```
$>  ls  
1.0.0  1.1.0
$>  pwd
/home/roman/Documents/softs/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle
```

How can I update the gradle plugin?

Comment: Post your full build.gradle. Did you add the mavenRepository?

Comment: There is my gradle build :

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D8nj8NcJ

Comment: just answered. Change your buildscript part.

Comment: check [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37267191/2826147)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `buildscript` block. You have to specify **also** in this block the repositories.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
    }
}
```

Also you can use the last version:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
```

Comment: Error:(121, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.

Comment: How do you find out what the latest version is?

Answer (score 2):

There are three type of dependency in Android gradle file.

**1. Module dependency**: other local project.

**2. Local dependency**: in your sdk path extras folder.

**3. Remote dependency**: JCenter, MavenCenter or third party maven path.

'com.android.tools.build:gradle' is local dependency, so you have to check your sdk and update.

P.S. If you tired with the version issue, you can try [andle](https://github.com/Jintin/andle).

It's an open source project to update your Android dependency version automatically.

See https://github.com/Jintin/andle for more information