# How to fix "Error:Cannot find JAR 'ivy-2.2.0.jar' required by module 'gradle-dependency-management' using classpath or distribution directory"?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an Android application in Android Studio.  When I try to create the project, it tells me that the Gradle refresh failed, with the error message

```
Error:Cannot find JAR 'ivy-2.2.0.jar' required by module 'gradle-dependency-management' using classpath or distribution directory 'C:\Gradle\gradle-2.10'
```

What is `ivy-2.2.0.jar`, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Updating the gradle version and plugin solved the issue for me by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272475/8383332

Answer (score 0):

As of 7/19/2017, I have seen that the `ivy-2.2.0.jar` file is included in both the binaries-only and the complete installations for Gradle.

The file is located here:
`gradle-4.0.1\lib\plugins\ivy-2.2.0.jar`

Ironically, I received the same issue when attempting to build one of Oculus's VR sample projects.
When switching to the complete installation, I no longer received this specific error.

Perhaps try switching to the complete installation, or migrating the project to use any Gradle Wrappers that might be available.

Answer (score -1):

This might happen if you are using the complete distribution with sources of Gradle. Try out the binary only distribution. It should work.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. this problem happen in bin only distribution