# Error: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I want to compile an open source android project (Netguard) using gradel (`gradlew clean build`) But I encountered this Error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: NdkComponentModelPlugin.Rules#cre
ateToolchains
   > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm
```

I serached but didn't find enything helping. Here is the main `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the `build.gradle` of the `app` project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "eu.faircode.netguard"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 2016011801
            versionName = "0.76"
            archivesBaseName = "NetGuard-v$versionName-$versionCode"
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "netguard"
        toolchain = "clang"
        ldLibs.add("log")
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir "src/main/jni/netguard"
                }
                exportedHeaders {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("all") {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.+'
}
```

And I'm using `gradle-2.9-all` and `android-ndk-r10e`. I don't know if I should mention anything else, so comment if you need any information.

Comment: Try to update the gradle tools.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05'

Comment: use https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases and Android NDK, Revision 16b (December 2017) version to download required folders and fix the issue.

Comment: Check this thread of [**three options** for solving this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)

Answer (score 416):

Two years has passed, now if you come across here, you may possibly encounterd error message like this:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix mips64el-linux-android

or

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix mipsel-linux-android

Latest NDK removed support for `mips` abi, and earler version of android gradle plugin still check for the existance of mips toolchain. [see here for more info](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/a7aee1b00acb81024869a205ae1cf07757c5b05f/CHANGELOG.md).

**Solution**: Upgrade android gradle plugin to 3.1 or newer.

e.g. Add following in the project level gradle [28-Sept-2018]

```
 classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0"
```

**Workaround**: Create `mipsel-linux-android` folder structure to fool the tool. The easiest way would be to symbolic link to `aarch64-linux-android-4.9`.

```
# on Mac
cd  ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains
ln -s aarch64-linux-android-4.9 mips64el-linux-android
ln -s arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 mipsel-linux-android
```

---

Check this thread of [**three options** for solving this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)

Comment: Tried with gradle 4.1, didn't work, but workaround (creation of folder mipsel-linux-android-dummy) worked. Thanks @lazybug.

Comment: @Girish upgrade **Android Gradle Plugin** in top level `build.gradle` file, something like `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-rc02`, not Gradle version

Comment: The Workaround mentioned here is the correct one:

`# on Mac
cd  ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains
ln -s aarch64-linux-android-4.9 mips64el-linux-android
ln -s arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 mipsel-linux-android`

Comment: On Windows:  `mklink /d mips64el-linux-android aarch64-linux-android-4.9` and `mklink /d mipsel-linux-android arm-linux-androideabi-4.9` worked for me too.

Comment: The "on Mac" workaround works fine (adapt ~/Library part).
But the next update of NDK (2018 Oct 14)  found a whole bunch of unexpected files in the mips* trees.  Not surprising.  So I removed the symbolic links again.

Comment: On windows create this folder structure to solve the error: `Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android\prebuilt`.

Comment: worked for me :  classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0"

Comment: From the cited link under 'see here for more info': "You will also need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 or newer." - Make sure you do that.

Comment: I upgraded to AS 3.2.1 and got this stupid dependency failure even though the project I'm building doesn't use NDK. I upgraded the project Gradle as per the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio and went through two passes of upgrades, including tools. Finally AS is back to baseline functionality. Gradle's purpose is to make these build problems go away, but maintaining Gradle is its own source of the problems.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Had exactly the same situation: forked a git project with implicit classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' in build.gradle. Changed to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' and everything started to compile fine.

Comment: Not working for me "ERROR: Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: MIPS".

Comment: The work around no longer works in android studio 3.3 on mac. After creating symbolic links receiving an index out of bounds -1 error during the gradle sync.  Very frustrating there is zero support for older gradle version, I thought the point of using a wrapper was to avoid this.

Comment: Creating twice symbolic links solved my problem on MacOS, Android Studio 3.3.

Comment: You can check your native dependencies' SO files, if any. It may contain SO for MIPS that is not supported anymore, thus making NDK fail. Removing those SO files for MIPS is safe, and it will make error disappear.

Comment: For me works this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76393#issuecomment-836625949

Answer (score 104):

I fixed this Error by uninstalling the NDK in the SDK-Tools.
So, if you don't need the NDK, uninstall it.

Comment: What if I need NDK?

Comment: same here if we want NDK then what is the solution for it?

Comment: Its fixed if uninstall the NDK but if you required to use NDK then please Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51589406/6533853

Comment: To uninstall follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207450/2768515

Comment: Its very strange despite the fact this is not the perfect answer to the problem , its still up voted .

Comment: works still in 2023 ;)

Comment: To solve the headache, let's kill the patient. Done!

Comment: This is the best solution. If you need NDK I believe it installs it for you automatically

Answer (score 71):

### For Android studio 3.2.1+

Upgrade your Gradle Plugin

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

If you are now getting this error:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
```

just add `google()` to your repositories, like this:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Check this thread of [**three options** for solving this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)

Comment: this worked for me . instead of this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Answer (score 39):

I have faced the same problem while update Android studio from 2.0 to 2.1 in my Windows 8 machine.

I found a solution for that.Please use the following steps.

1. Download the android NDK for windows from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html.
2. Extract the same and copy the "toolchain" folder from the bundle.
3. Paste the folder under installed NDK folder under C:\android-sdk-win\ndk-bundle.[Installed the path may vary based on your installation]
4. Restart android studio.

This is happening because Android studio won't gets full NDK update in the stable channel. If you are not using NDK for your project development you can simply remove the NDK folder from your SDK directory.

Comment: Works with Android Studio 3.2!

Comment: This also worked for me for fixing the error "`Error : Android MIPS ToolChain directory "" does not exist`" in Game Maker Studio 2 on a Mac.

But I needed to get version 17c of the NDK from here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

(as per: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/9m958a/no_toolchains_found_in_the_ndk_toolchains_folder/)

Thank You @nithinjith !

... still not building however, need to solve : `Android NDK: Please fix the APP_ABI definition in /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/default-application.mk `

Answer (score 37):

Error message:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm.

After fresh web installation of Android Studio with NDK, I imported an Android code sample that used NDK from GitHub and tried to compile it.

As a result had an Error:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm

**Solution:**
for some reasons standard installation process on macOS had failed to install a complete set:

`~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` had missed folder `toolchains` with all tools,

(it should be like this: `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains`)

The solution was to download NDK separately, open it, copy folder `toolchain` and paste it to the folder:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

Comment: in my case it's there but no file there with prefix _aarch64-linux-android_. Any suggestion !!

Comment: folder 'mips64el-linux-android-4.9' & 'mipsel-linux-android-4.9' are not available after ndk bundle 16, so i have to download and add these two folder in android sdk bundle inside toolchains folder hence issue solved, still didn't understand why this error?

Comment: Check this thread of [**three options** for solving this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)

Answer (score 27):

Step-by-step:

**1)** Open the page with old **NDK** versions:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

[image]

**2)** Agree the Terms:

[image]

**3)** Download the older version of `NDK` (for example 16b):

[image]

**4)** Open your `toolchains` directory.

**5)** Transfer files that you need from `toolchains` folder of downloaded zip-file to your `toolchains` folder:

[image]

**6)** Rebuild the Project:

[image]

---

**UPD 30 Sep 2018:**
I used Android NDK Revision r16b for fix this error in my own case. So I present the example with this version.
But  it's better to use the Android NDK, Revision r17c (June 2018). It is the last one, supporting mips (reasonable reccomendation from Weekend's comment).

Comment: Instead of `(for example 16b)`, it's better to clarify which NDK version is the last one supporting mips. via [release note of Android NDK Revision r17c (June 2018)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history): _Support for ARMv5 (armeabi), MIPS, and MIPS64 has been removed. Attempting to build any of these ABIs will result in an error._ It's `16b` exactly.

Comment: @Weekend Thanks for your recommendation. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @vmarch Sorry but **It's `16b` exactly.** r17c is the first version which **removed** the support for MIPS :)

Comment: @Oh, I read your previous comment so very quickly. That's why I missed the point. My apologize! But these files are still present in the Android NDK, Revision r17c (June 2018).
And in version 18 they were finally removed.  
Just look into the archive.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases#ndk-17c-downloads

Comment: @vmarch Well done! I didn't check r17c archive, just inferred the previous conclusion from release notes.

Comment: awesome solution - exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 20):

The best solution for this problem is:

1. Go to SDK Manager.
2. Next choose SDK tools.
3. Unselect NDK (side by side).
4. Apply and OK.

Comment: easy! tnx for the quick solution

Answer (score 18):

Without downloading, copying, or symlinking anything, I was able to "fix" the error by simply creating an empty directory where the older version of the Android Gradle plugin expects the removed mips toolchain:

```
mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

Obviously, `$ANDROID_HOME` points to the root of the Android SDK installation here. **If you are using MacOS**, replace `linux-x86_64` with `darwin-x86_64` in the command above. On Windows use `windows-x86_64`.

Comment: Worked like charm.

Comment: Depends on what your project refers to. Did not work for me, but is a nice and simple trick for some. I had to copy the real toolchain to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 16):

I uninstalled the NDK since I didn't need it . Go to SDK manager on Android studio ( Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager ) . If NDK is installed . Just uncheck the box and click OK . The installed components will be deleted .

Answer (score 10):

To resolve the issue just go to:

**tools->Sdk Manager -> Android Sdk -> SDK Tools** in Android Studio and
Uncheck the NDK versions and only select 20.1.5948944 version and install that.
[image]

I resolved the same issue in linux(Ubuntu) machine using this technique.

Comment: On Catalina removed NDK and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this error occured when creating a new **Android Studio (Android studio 3.2.1)** Java Project with

> ```
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
> ```

So I´ve downgraded to

```
       dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
      }
```

Not the best solution stay at an older version, but maybe it´s just a temporary  bug in the beta as the NDK path in **local.properties** is still the same, but the IDE doesn´t complain anymore

Comment: I think this is a bug of outdated gradle plugin. Just update to the latest one. It helped to me (from 3.0 to 3.2.0-beta05 in my case)

Comment: I think It's upgraded not downgraded ... P

Answer (score 7):

Android NDK 18.0* seems has an issue not creating all the files in folders after extraction. Due to it, your app compilation will fail which uses ndk builds.

Better is to use NDK 17.1* (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/) etc version and you can extract or use the android studio extraction to ndk-bundle by default will work good.

Answer (score 5):

Open Android Studio, Go to Tools then Android and then SDK, uncheck NDK If you do not need this, and restart android studio.

Answer (score 5):

[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android][1]

For people trying out this example and facing issues with latest NDK. Can follow this solution.
In build.gradle
change this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

The reason is mips are deprecated in the latest ndk versions, Gradle version 3.1.2   will not have a compulsion for mips. It assumes the presence for these missing folders.

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution is download and extract the following file which contains mips64el-linux-android-4.9  and mipsel-linux-android-4.9 folders,to your toolchains folder inside sdk "android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains".

[Downlod this file and extraxt to toolchains foolder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ynaT-KhBbH2w61i5-MvOKbk-1FW5xw8N/view)

Comment: Extract and then execute
# on Mac
cd  ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains

ln -s aarch64-linux-android-4.9 mips64el-linux-android

ln -s arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 mipsel-linux-android

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue. Installed latest NDK rc version by default. Latest stable release fixed the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

When compiling a project in android studio, I occasionally encounter:

> Error: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with
> prefix: arm-linux-androideabi/llvm

This may be caused by updating related components. The solution is to Android studio ( Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager ) .
Select the ndk item and delete it. If the program needs it, you can re-install it. This will ensure that the folder location is correct and there will be no such problem.

Comment: I deleted it. But when I compile my app, ndk is downloaded again.  Did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

After looking around, the solution was to remove the NDK designation from my preferences.

Android Studio → Preferences → System Settings → Android SDK → SDK Tools → Unselect NDK → Apply button.

Project and Gradle compiled fine after that and I was able to move on with my project work.

As far as why this is happening, I do not know but for more info on NDK check out:

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling the ndk solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem, but I wanted to use NDK version r9d due to project requirements.

In `local.properties` the path was set to `ndk.dir=C\:\\Android\\ndk\\android-ndk-r9d` but that lead to the problem:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: [toolchain-name]

The solution was to:

1. Install the newest NDK using sdk manager
2. Copy the missing toolchain [toolchain-name] from the new ndk to the old. In my case from `sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains` to `\ndk\android-ndk-r9d\toolchains`
3. Repeat the process till all the required toolchains are there

It looks to me that the copied toolchains are not used, but for some reason it is needed to for them be there.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by adding `google()` dependency into both repositories in `build.gradle`(Project: ProjectName). then sync your project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your project level Gradle file increase the dependencies 
 classpath version low to high like

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
```

to change like

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this question by unInstalled ndk, becasuse I dont't need it

Answer (score 2):

I navigated to local.properties, and in there the

```
ndk.dir=/yo/path/for/NDK
```

line needs to be updated to where your ndk lies.

I was using Crystax NDK, and didn't realize the original Android NDK was still in use.

Answer (score 2):

*Find your own local android-SDK, if you download the relevant SDK of ndk, there will be a folder called "ndk-bundle"*

[image]

There is a folder called "toolchains" inside.

[image]

We noticed that there are no mips64el related files inside.

[image]

**The solution is as follows:**

[Click here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/?hl=zh-en) to download the NDK package separately through the browser. After unzipping, open the "toolchains" folder, compare it with the android-sdk->ndk-bundle->toolchains folder, find the missing folder, copy the past three. Recompile, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it like i did

Android Studio
File> project structure and go to project

change Gradle version to 4.6
&
Android plugin version to 3.2.1

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkHIb.png)

then clean project if you got this Error "Could not find aapt2-proto.jar"

go to build.gradle (project)

Try moving the google() method (.gradle file) to the top of its execution block
the order of repositories it searches in that causes the issue.

for example, change this:

```
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  google()      <===  from here
  mavenCentral()
}
```

To this:

```
repositories {
  google()     <===  to here
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Make those changes in both  "buildscript"  and  "allprojects "

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SET4B.png)

If you didn't find google() add it

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio 3.2.1 Update your

Gradle Version **4.6**

Android plugin version **3.2.1**

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes mostly when you are cloning a previous project specially from github. What you can do is

1. Change the classpath to

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'**

in your project level gradle.

2. Then Change all the instances of compile with implementation except **compileSdkVersion** keep it as it is in your app level gradle.
3. Instead of **sync now** click on **make project(Ctrl+F9)**
4. Add google maven repositories if needed.
5. Upgrade the gradle wrapper if needed.

(Android Studio IDE will ask / guide you with the same for steps 4 and 5)

Answer (score 2):

I try to solve the problem using following method:

1. Stay Android build tools version the same with gradle version. For example:if you use the  build tools version is 3.3.0,your gradle version must be 4.10.1.You can reference by the link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin and chagne your build tools &  gradle version in your AS(File->Project Structure->Project)
2. If method1 don't work,you can custom your ndk toolchains version to solve the problem :like download ndk18 or ndk16 , setting the ndk path is your AS(File->Project Structure->SDK Location->Android NDK Location)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `C:\Users\lalit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains`.

Now, find the folder name `aarch64-linux-android-4.9` and rename it to `mips64el-linux-android`.

Re-run the android app.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all your NDK in sdk tools.

Answer (score 1):

For me I think there might be some issue in installing android NDK from android studio. I was able to resolve this in following manner

Downloaded android ndk from

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

and placed inside ndk-bundle (where your android sdk is installed ). For more info check this screens.

https://app.box.com/s/dfi4h9k7v4h0tmbu3z9qnqx3d12fdejn

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the NDK, unset the environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by reinstalling the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic 3 Remove ndk from android studio sdk tools.

Comment: Great, as a temporary solution for the specific need of building ionic android projects, although is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Open your buldle.gradle file and upgrade the versions for following both classpath:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Then Sync and after get one dialog for update Gradle version as well then click that link and wait for download all required updates.

Answer (score 1):

First, try updating the ndk version
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/

If that's not working then you can try the following:

- **Create a folder**

  Go to the Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains folder (in my case its
  C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains; you
  can find yours under File->project structure->SDK location in you
  android studio) and create a folder with the name that's shown as
  missing in the error for eg: if the error is

  > Gradle sync failed: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android

  Then create a folder with name mipsel-linux-android
- **Include content**
  Go to the Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains folder again and open any folder that's already in it.
  For example:Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9
  (in mycase C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9)
  copy the **prebuilt** folder in it to the folder we created in the last step

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This answer seems to be specific to: `No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android`, but it was linked here by:*

** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193274/no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-mips64el-l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193274/no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-mips64el-l_)*

From NDK r19b:

```
more ~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/CHANGELOG.md
```

- This version of the NDK is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin
  version 3.0 or older. If you see an error like
  `No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android`,
  update your project file to [use plugin version 3.1 or newer]. You will also
  need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case some supporting file was missing in new NDK version "23.0.7599858" so i downgraded the version to "22.1.7171670".You can also find all the downloaded version of NDK at "../Sdk/ndk".

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    ...
    ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in `local.properties(SDK Location)`

```xml
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps I have followed to fix the issue are as follows:

1. `Analyze -> Code Cleanup`
2. `File -> Project Structures -> Select project from the list and update the gradle version to latest.`
3. `Build -> Clean Project`
4. `Build -> Make Project`

Now the issue related to the build may get reported like using compile instead of implementation etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add NDK in your project then follow below steps:

1. If you installed NDK using SDK Manager then uninstall first. (untick from SDK tools and apply)
2. Download manually NDK from its official site. (any version) if project old then prefer version 17.
3. Extract that file.
4. Go to your project structure > NDK path > add Extracted file path here.
5. Build Project.

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade your Gradle Plugin**

1. com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4
   **Upgrade gradle wraperpropeties**

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Open android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties and change this line:
distributionUrl=

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

to this line:

distributionUrl=

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Open android/build.gradle and change this line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update project gradle version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Update app gradle:`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Comment: this worked with gradle-wrapper.properties url set to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the older version of SDK from IntellJ IDEA -> Appearance -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK platforms.

Install the new Android SDK version whatever version you want.

**While installing the new SDK, uncheck the NDK checkbox under SDK tools.**

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade you Android Studio with latest version >> connect with the internet for download content according to your project.

Answer (score 0):

link file is not good for me.

```
ln -s aarch64-linux-android-4.9 mips64el-linux-android
ln -s arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 mipsel-linux-android
```

Because there is another error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Test'.
> Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: MIPS
```

Add this in defaultConfig if you build with gralde

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

If you use ndk-build command, add this in Application.mk.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue with your older gradle version, we can use below solution:

Notice the file android-ndk-r17-beta2/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-
4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/NOTICE-MIPS64. The content of the file is below.

This mips64el-linux-android-4.9 directory exists to make the NDK compatible with the Android
SDK's Gradle plugin, version 3.0.1 and earlier, which expects the NDK
to have a MIPS64 toolchain directory.

So, i can say, using Android SDK's Gradle plugin above 3.0.1, or create even a directory marked with 'mipsel' and 'mips64el', can both resolve the problem. The latter method is below.

cd "path-to-ndk"

```
OS_=$(uname -s | tr [A-Z] [a-z])
mkdir -p toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${OS_}-x86_64
touch toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${OS_}-x86_64/NOTICE-MIPS
mkdir -p toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${OS_}-x86_64
touch toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${OS_}-x86_64/NOTICE-MIPS64
```

Got the solutions from [here](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-446058373)

Answer (score 0):

First go to SDK folder by using following location **C:\Users\CHALAKMIAN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**
find Ndk folder and delete it. Know run your project

Answer (score 0):

Use this option to filter out wish Abi prefix to be used:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64', ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle to

In your
*gradle-wrapper.properties* file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

And in your *android/build.gradle* file

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Update `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X'` in Project Build.Gradle and replace **X** to the latest version you have.

Answer (score -1):

Change gradle version of project-label .gradle file to Latest:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

and add these checks on app label .gradle file:

```
packagingOptions{
    doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
    doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Download an older version of the NDK (14b) and go to Android Studio to File | Project Structure and select it.