# Gradle 'MyApp' project refresh failed. A strange kind of error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-8, linux-toolchain, android-gradle-2.0

I have recently update Android Studio to Android Studio 2.1.2. I have stuck with a strange error. Error is printed below. This happens when I just create new android studio project.

```
Gradle 'myapp' project refresh failed
Error:No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: aarch64-linux-android
```

Note : I am using java8 and the module gradle.build file looks like below. Since I have just created the project I have not added any NDK related files.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yes it did. Thanks :-)