# "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored..."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio 3, I'm seeing this issue:

> The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored, as
>   it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle
>   Plugin 3.0.0.
>
> Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
>
> To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'" from
>   your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin
>   now has a default version of the build tools.

The problem is that because these are third-party/vendor modules that have `buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'`, I can't modify their build.gradle without forking each submodule.

Is there a way to set a global `buildToolsVersion` that will override all the sub build.gradles?

Comment: Looks like it's doing it for you?

Comment: It's not. It says it's a "warning", but it's coming up as an error and halting the build process.

Comment: Please update your SDK and set gradle to 27.0.1, now say `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` (gradle-wrapper in gradle-dir) a try. Next delete both build-dirs and rebuild..

Comment: You can drop back to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`. You'll get the "convert this project" dialog again, which you can either keep ignoring or tell it to stop nagging you.

Comment: Just use a global var and change the buildToolsVersion in the build.gradle file of the third-party libraries.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @MohamedOun see the fix below.

Comment: @Snowman I encountered the same issue, resolved by adding following snippet to the root build.gradle
subprojects {
    ...
    afterEvaluate { subproject ->
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || 
            subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 17):

Here if you are referring to my previous answers Here is an Update. 
1. Compile would be removed from the dependencies after 2018.

a new version build Gradle is available.

[image]

Use the above-noted stuff it will help you to resolve the errors. It is needed for the developers who are working after March 2018. Also, maven update might be needed. All above answers will not work on the Android Studio 3.1. Hence Above code block is needed to be changed if you are using 3.1. See also I replaced compile by implementation.

Comment: This is the latest answer, and the one that should be used. It worked for me, to use sdk version 27!

Comment: I am using 3.1. Do you mean to say make these changes in build Gradle in all modules or only for module app? (OP is also saying `I can't modify their build.gradle` for third-party/vendor modules)

Comment: @Atul When making a new app on 3.1.3 or greater. I have seen the android studio generally making all changes as I mentioned above but when we import projects via Github generally API versions are of a lower level Hence we have to make changes in the Build.gradle file (Module: app) with Dependencies changes also to be done. As part of question stated Answer is YES only in Module: App. (Build.gradle) & we generally are not doing anything in other modules as per the original topic question so as to build & sync gradle project in Android Studio. Hope I am clear in explaining.

Comment: One new problem might appear No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android. So Please look after that situation.

Comment: @RahulJoshi I had the same problem like: "No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder...". Look this answer. I have fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv/52454806#52454806

Comment: @V.March Thanks, I was so frustrated as Gradle build was not happening which lead to the non-responsive Android studio (Non-Editable & Debuggable code)

Answer (score 14):

Open *app/build.gradle* file

Change `buildToolsVersion` to `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"`

change `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'`

Comment: use `implementation` instead of `compile` as its deprecated since 2018

Answer (score 7):

Solution to this problem is simple

Go to build.gradle (module.app) file

[image: Change the Build Version for app as shown in the photo link]

It will help us to rebuild gradle for the project, to make it sync again.

Answer (score 6):

Update to Android Studio 3.0.1 which treats these as warnings. 
Android 3.0 was treating such warnings as errors and hence causing the gradle sync operation to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` then change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`.

Make sure you set `compileSdkVersion` to `26` whiles `targetSdkVersion` is also set `26`.

It is also appropriate to sent set `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'`.

Answer (score 1):

just clean and make project / rebuilt fixed my issue give a try :-)

Answer (score 1):

invalidate cache in android studio will resolve this issue. Go to file-> click on invalidate cache/restart option.

Answer (score 0):

Many times as API's are updated. We forgot to update SDK Managers. For accessing recent API's one should always have highest API Level updated if possible should also have other regularly used lower level APIs to accommodate backward compatibility.
Go to build.gradle (module.app) file
change compileSdkVersion
       buildToolsVersion
       targetSdkVersion, all should have the highest level of API.