# React Native The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I've already tried the solutions posted here: ["The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146694/the-specified-android-sdk-build-tools-version-26-0-0-is-ignored) Upgrading to 26.0.2 did not work.

When running the project build I get the following output which ends in an error indicating that none of the native components I have could be built.

```
> Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :react-native-code-push
Configuration 'compile' in project ':react-native-code-push' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :react-native-config
Configuration 'compile' in project ':react-native-config' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

// MORE SIMILAR ERRORS

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules (41ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules (38ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 11 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

> Task :app:generateBundledResourcesHashRelease
3622136b779320920670db60021d0cc296185e0ef9755b7aedf4083189c67cb5

> Task :react-native-code-push:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/codepush/react/CodePushNativeModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-fcm:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-fcm/android/src/main/java/com/evollu/react/fcm/SendNotificationTask.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-intercom:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-intercom/android/src/main/java/com/robinpowered/react/Intercom/IntercomModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-intercom/android/src/main/java/com/robinpowered/react/Intercom/IntercomModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-photo-view:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-push-notification:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-video:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch6/gauge-insights-respondent/node_modules/react-native-video/android/src/main/java/com/brentvatne/react/ReactVideoViewManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:releaseStagingRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-intercom.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-intercom:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-video.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-video:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseStaging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
   // MORE "Could not resolve project..."

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
215 actionable tasks: 190 executed, 25 up-to-date
```

The reason this happens is that each of the dependencies are not generating a 'lib' file.

Here is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

and my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gauge"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.2.10"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Note: CodePush updates should not be tested in Debug mode as they are overriden by the RN packager. However, because CodePush checks for updates in all modes, we must supply a key.
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'
        }
        releaseStaging {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"1psOppiGxP0-cJpCePhMqgEjeO4l2533309f-9929-415c-8999-d7fda42c3857"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"0wPxPhihmtxxEdma3mU4zIGIFNdi2533309f-9929-415c-8999-d7fda42c3857"'
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-intercom')
    compile project(':react-native-video')

    compile (project(':react-native-code-push')) {
        exclude(group: 'android.arch.core')
    }
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile(project(':react-native-radar')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
        exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
      transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to install some compatibility models like android.support.v7.

Just delete build folders and try again.