# Android gradle plugin and android sdk build tools

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I m about to use with react native, and certain library but imnot sure what to do these days after this error, been searching but only got more confused.

```
The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
```

Imnot sure what to do with this,

1. do I should change the updated version to 25.0.0 ? or
2. change android plugin to match build tools 25 ? or
3. or should i change the project to 28.0.0 ? and I dont think i can do this one yet, since i wanna try to use this library.
4. this is a warning, but could i actually still use it?? because I thought it still working but its not.

I have been changing android grade plugin version to lower but it seems doesn't work.
also i hve problem understanding `Android gradle plugin version` vs `gradle version`:

1. I dont know how to change Gradle version, should I download the update ? but i cant find it nowhere.
2. if I have high gradle version but lower gradle plugin, then it should be still working right ?? or not ?? I did googed and searched but now I mixed up again between those 2.

should I change the build.gradle :

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

every 28 to 25 ??? but it still doesnt work

what do I actually have to do ??

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146694/the-specified-android-sdk-build-tools-version-26-0-0-is-ignored , it may provide some usefull information.

Comment: actually did, but still dont get it, it leaves me more confuse @DuyiLian