# Could not create task ':react-native-alarm-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native

I have installed this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-alarm-manager and now upon running the android application it gives me this error
**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':tasks'.

> Could not create task ':react-native-alarm-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools. In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above

**

I am using v0.72.4 of React native

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146694/the-specified-android-sdk-build-tools-version-26-0-0-is-ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your React Native project, you have an android directory. Inside of it, there could be several places where the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion will be defined.
One option is the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 
  ....
```

Another option could be the `gradle.properties` file

Just make sure to update the values to be 30 (or above).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error this package needs `compileSdkVersion` to be 30+. As you are already on 0.72.x react-native you can do following changes:

in project level `build.gradle` inside `ext` change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `33`
clean gradle and run you app. It should work

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        //...other changes
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
```

Comment: this is the current present code in it 

     ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }

Comment: seems like issue is in library itself

inside ```node_modules/react-native-alarm-manager/android/build.gradle```

replace ```completSdkVersion``` and ```targetSdkVersion``` with

```compileSdkVersion safeExtGet("compileSdkVersion", 33)
targetSdkVersion safeExtGet("targetSdkVersion", 33)```

also add 

```def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
  rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}```

Than you can try to run, if it works you can patch-package using https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

Comment: its still throwing me this error > Task :react-native-alarm-manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED