# transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease execution failed with mips64el-linux-android-strip

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am getting this error in android studio, please anyone know how to solve it let me know

```
Execution failed for task ':q84sale-base:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/amira/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip''
```

Comment: If someone is getting this issue in AS and jitpack, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858722/jitpack-build-failed-with-error-time-out-getting-container-status

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Reasons:**

According to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18#known-issues

> This version of the NDK is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin version 3.0 or older. If you see an error like `No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android`, update your project file to use plugin version 3.1 or newer. You will also need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 or newer.

---

As said above:

> update your project file to use plugin version 3.1 or newer. You will also need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 or newer.

**The Direct solution is:**

From your TOP-LEVEL `build.gradle`, **change your classpath for android gradle plugin to 3.2.1 or higher**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

---

**But**, if you want to stick to your existing Gradle plugin version, the **workarounds/solutions are as below:**

**Option 1:**

There is no more `mips` architecture since `ndk-17`. So, you can either downgrade your NDK (for older versions of NDK, please check from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) or add abiFilters to exclude `mips` ABIs.

Seeing that your are using **ndk-bundle** which is the default ndk path settings of Android Studio. You can configure this path from **`local.properties`** making it point at your NDK version, e.g. *r16b*, rather than the default `ndk-bundle`.

```
ndk.dir=<path>/android-ndk-r16b
sdk.dir=<path>/sdk
```

**Option 2:**

Using below configuration to only filter the necessary ABIs.

```
android {
    // Similar to other properties in the defaultConfig block, you can override
    // these properties for each product flavor in your build configuration.
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            // Tells Gradle to build outputs for the following ABIs and package
            // them into your APK.
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you are using `cmake`

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
    release {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

Another workaround is to skip the stripping of mips using below configuration:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
    }
    ...
}
```

Choose the best option for your case.

Comment: it is already configured in local.properties, also I have downloaded an older version of ndk, and still the same error

Comment: Try to add abiFilter to exclude mips

Comment: how and where should I add them ?

Comment: the main problem in ffmpeg4android library

Comment: I did the first option and also use ndk-16, and now I am getting the error in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853765/can-not-generate-signed-apk-android-studio

Comment: Thanks Bro. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Gradle version is `3.5.4`, Android is Bumblebee and NDK is 24.xxx; Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to open an old project,
I solved the problem by deleting the **ndk** folder in the Android SDK path  *Android/sdk/ndk*.
Then run the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was to download older ndk version `20.0.5594570`
then in `local.properties` set those.

```
sdk.dir=/Users/YOUR USER/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/YOUR USER/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570
```

make sure to replace `YOUR USER` with your path.

worked for me on mac