# How to stop gradle from looking for the Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android project which **doesn't** use the NDK jet Gradle is looking for the NDK.

Either I get this Error:

```
 No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
```

Or I get this warning:

```
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.
```

Even when `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` and `ndk.dir` is unset. It there a way to built the system without those annoying messages?

Comment: Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to download the NDK (from: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/) separately and unzip it to your prefered location, e.g. `~/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r18b`
2. Open your `local.properties` file which probably looks like below

   ```
    ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
    sdk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk
   ```
3. Change the `ndk.dir` to `~/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r18b`

Or you can try the solution from here: https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-415423557

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the NDK or update your gradle plugin version. There was a bug in older versions of the plugin where it would perform an invalid sanity check on the NDK even for a Java only project. IIRC 3.2 is the fixed version.

Comment: What is worse then no sanity check? A faulty sanity check!

It's better to have no sanity check then to have an invalid sanity check so one should think twice before adding one.

Answer (score 0):

check your build.gradle file, if you have something like this in externalNativeBuild tag;

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' ...
     }
```

or like this;

```
cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
```

or maybe like this;

```
cmake {
            path 'src/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
```

try to remove them

Comment: I **don't** have an `externalNativeBuild` tag. Because it's a bog standard java project. **NO** native and **NO** external stuff at all. 