# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I had a working project, but there was some problem with Android studio displaying the breakpoints, so I uninstalled the Android Studio on my mac, reinstalled it and opened the same working project. Strangely it gives the below error and I cant do anything with that. None of the fixes suggested online seem to help the scenario.

Is there anything to do with the uninstall of the first version of the Android Studio?

There is absolutely no change in the code of my project. The same project is working perfectly on my teammates' Android Studio. Below is the error I am getting :

> "No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android"
>
> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred 
>         configuring project ':app'.
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.getDefaultToolchainVersion(DefaultNdkInfo.java:330)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.getToolchainPath(DefaultNdkInfo.java:207)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.DefaultNdkInfo.getStripExecutable(DefaultNdkInfo.java:300)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getStripExecutable(NdkHandler.java:333)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.StripDebugSymbolTransform.(StripDebugSymbolTransform.java:73)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createStripNativeLibraryTask(TaskManager.java:1339)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(ApplicationTaskManager.java:289)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:485)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:293)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$3.call(VariantManager.java:290)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:286)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>       at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease execution failed with mips64el-linux-android-strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850591/transformnativelibswithstripdebugsymbolforrelease-execution-failed-with-mips64el)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Gradle Plugin

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

or go to :

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

and download NDK 17 
   https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

change NDK in /android/sdk/ndk-bundle with new NDK 17

and change the classpath to :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hey Hichem, I placed the downloaded android-ndk-r17c folder in the ndk-bundle folder. Still that doesnt seem to work. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: change the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Comment: I changed classpath to 3.2.1, then show the following message Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 3.3.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Gradle settings. When I clicked on FIx Gradle wrapper, it gave the following error:  Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=goldProdDebug, filters=[], versionCode=4202448, versionName=3.7-debug}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.

Comment: Change classpth to 2.2.2

Comment: again its giving ndk tool chains error after changing classpath to 2.2.2

Comment: Hey, Thanks a ton, its finally fixed. I replaced the contents of toolchains folder in ndk-bundle with the contents of toolchains folder downloaded from NDK-17 bundle.

Comment: @HichemRomdhane, "You post my solution that's not good", you can **flag** this behaviour to leave it to the stackoverflow moderator to handle this.

Comment: @shizhen beleive me i don't look your solution , i have this problem before in april and i fixed that lonely if you want i can show the code source of this project

Comment: Oops, no worries, Hichem, I am afraid you misunderstood me. I just voted up your answer to show my support to it. Also, note that there is a quotation mark surrounding "You post my solution that's not good". I actually was suggesting you to flag this kind of behaviour. Because I ever encountered such kind of behviours before and understand your feelings. Appending my answer link was just to express we have the same solution. -:) Hope you understand me this time ...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18#known-issues

> This version of the NDK is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin version 3.0 or older. If you see an error like No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android, update your project file to use plugin version 3.1 or newer. You will also need to upgrade to Android Studio 3.1 or newer.

The workarounds are as below:
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)

**Option 1:**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
    release {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
    }
    ...
}
```