# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am getting the following error:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for the ABI with
>   prefix: mipsel-linux-android

Comment: If have some some hypothesys, please, can you share in the question, giving us more details? Thank you

Comment: Show the code that produces this error...

Comment: I had downloaded a project from gitlab and when I tried to compile it gave me the error in question. I was able to solve as reported in the answer. Thank you all.

Comment: Presumably you have a project that contains some native code, and you haven't set an abiFilter (or your abiFilter includes all ABIs, even obsolete ones). Building for MIPS is no longer supported so you must set your abiFilter to exclude it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50944898/192373

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease execution failed with mips64el-linux-android-strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850591/transformnativelibswithstripdebugsymbolforrelease-execution-failed-with-mips64el)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53489287/7055487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` (Project: XXX) file, in dependencies I updated the classpath as follows:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Note: you have to enter the most recent version

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (a very unexpected "No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android") when I opened an old project, and fixed it by updating some build settings:

Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Comment: Just for the one who are restricted to upgrade gradle plugin version, you can check workaround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839.