# Android build targets "No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains"

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to build an old project and something has changed where the project tries to target `mips64el-linux-android`. I don't reference this build targets within in build variants and it's not the sdk build version I specify in the project properties panel. Even so, I do have the native sdk installed so it should build in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850591/transformnativelibswithstripdebugsymbolforrelease-execution-failed-with-mips64el/51852529#51852529

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease execution failed with mips64el-linux-android-strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850591/transformnativelibswithstripdebugsymbolforrelease-execution-failed-with-mips64el)

Answer (score 0):

1.Donwload [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/) package
2.Open the "toolchains" folder after unzipping
3.Compare with android-sdk->ndk-bundle->toolchains folder
4.Find the missing folder and copy it in the past
5.Recompile

Answer (score 0):

Which NDK version are you using? Google has dropped mips support in NDK r17.

You need to download older NDK for older projects. I use NDK r10e and sometimes r14 for my older projects. If project is too old you can try with r10.

In your project build script you need to specify downloaded NDK's path. You need to download and manually extract NDK (I believe Android Studio will not download older version).