# Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: MIPS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Getting an error when trying to fix error -

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix `mips64el-linux-android`

Do not want to upgrade as afraid it might break my application and need to use NDK to work with C++.

After following steps for workaround to fix the error - 
[Error: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv)

New error:

> Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: MIPS

Any help on how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify an ABI filter.

You haven't mentioned how you are building. If you're using Gradle, then you put something like this in the `defaultConfig` block in your `build.gradle`:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

---

If you're invoking `ndk-build` directly, then you put this on the `ndk-build` command line:

```
APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
```

Or inside your `Application.mk`:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
```

---

The ABI filter I showed is just an example. It's up to you to decide which ones you want to build for. `arm64-v8a` and `armeabi-v7a` are by far the most common ones among Android devices.
`mips`, `mips64` and `armeabi` are no longer supported by the NDK.

Comment: buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
                //abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

Comment: I just started a new project and added NDK on complain from android studio and getting these error. I tried to add ndk in my project using your above methods. But its not working.

Comment: Why did you add the ABI filter only for the `debug` build type instead of for all build types?

Comment: I was just testing not sure but irrespective it giving me same error on buildtypes or build.

Comment: You can also update your gradle plugin version to one that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks Micahel it works now. I needed to call ndk in android {

Answer (score 1):

From your TOP-LEVEL `build.gradle`, change your classpath for android gradle plugin to `3.2.1` or higher.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Or for other options, please check here: [**Three options** for solving this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852529/8034839)