# JitPack build failed with ERROR: Time-out getting container status

Tags: jitpack

I am trying to deploy some of my jar libraries through JitPack. So far I am still testing things out, thus version codes are `dev-SNAPSHOT` or `master-SNAPSHOT` for the libraries.

For most libraries this seems to work well (at least as far as fetching the artifacts goes); however, one library had a failed build for `master-SNAPSHOT`.

The corresponding build, `master-36ef0715cd-1`, reports failure. The last lines of the log read:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.995 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-23T06:52:54Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Found module: org.traffxml:traff-source-android:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: org.traffxml:traff-source-android:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ERROR: Time-out getting container status
Error building
```

So, apparently, the jar got built but fetching container status failed after that. This could well be an issue with JitPack’s infrastructure: over the last couple hours, it has taken several retries to get the artifacts to build, and I do not see any difference between this library and the others which built successfully.

How can I retry the failed build, or otherwise fix this (other than by going the crude way of pushing a new commit to my repo)?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I had to commit more changes, which eventually solved this for the moment.

On the long run, one thing to try:

- Go to https://jitpack.io/
- In the box, enter your group and artifact ID, and click **Look up**.
- In the list of availale builds, click the **Branches** tab.
- Look for the corresponding `-SNAPSHOT` build for your branch, and click **Get it**.

No guarantee this works, but it did trigger a new build after pushing a new commit. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: This works! The build log messages clearly suggest it was a successful build, but the error message we got `Time-out getting container status` seems to be an internal error between jitpack frontend and the container that builds the libraries. Using this hack does work, but a better way would be to allow for build retrials in jitpack

Comment: Even better would be for JitPack to solve their communication problems 