# publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: check here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv

Comment: And here: https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-422775099