# Game Maker Studio 2 : Android : Error in NDK : setup-app.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, mips, game-maker-studio-2

In Game Maker Studio 2, when trying to build for Android, I am getting the following error :

```
ClangExeLocation=/Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
Using NDKDir = /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
Using PlatformDir = /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-28
Using ARMToolChain = /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
Using ARM64ToolChain = /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
saving file /var/folders/_n/dj0hlyp12xz_c2_9pjwgktt00000gn/GameMakerStudio2/GMS2TEMP/dungeon_crawler_4CD6562A_YYC/dungeon crawler.droid
Android NDK: android-14 is unsupported. Using minimum supported version android-16.    
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be compatible with devices older than android-16. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.    
Android NDK: The armeabi ABI is no longer supported. Use armeabi-v7a.    
Android NDK: NDK Application 'local' targets unknown ABI(s): armeabi    
Android NDK: Please fix the APP_ABI definition in /Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/default-application.mk    
/Users/../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/setup-app.mk:79: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Stats : GMA : Elapsed=937.265
Stats : GMA : sp=144,au=0,bk=0,pt=1,sc=2,sh=0,fo=2,tl=0,ob=35,ro=16,da=2,ex=4,ma=130,fm=0x1080A31D6F7C2220



/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono exited with non-zero status (2)

elapsed time 00:00:13.6687480s for command "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono" /Users/Shared/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes/runtime-2.2.0.258/bin/Igor.exe -options="/var/folders/_n/dj0hlyp12xz_c2_9pjwgktt00000gn/GameMakerStudio2/GMS2TEMP/build.bff"  -- Android Package started at 10/27/2018 16:03:18
FAILED: Package Program Complete
```

*Previously I was getting "Error : Android MIPS ToolChain directory "" does not exist" but I managed to get past that by installing an earlier version (17c) of the NDK toolchain. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv/38306459#comment92940916_38306459))*

#### Versions

Game Maker Studio 2 : IDE Version : 2.2.0.343
Android Studio : 3.2.1
Android APIs installed : 14, 16, 28
Android NDK : 18 (but with the toolchains directory overwritten with the 17c version of that directory)

**What do I need to do so as to get NDK to allow an Android build from Game Maker ?**

Comment: Why do you feel the need to build for `armeabi`? The last time non-ARMv7/v8 Android devices were a thing was back in 2009 or so.

Comment: Not wedded to `armeabi` at all ... don't even know what it is ... if you can tell me how to turn it off in Game Maker, or aim for a higher version or whatever, then I'll mark that as the correct answer ... I'm just going to try and find that now ...

Comment: Well, the error message suggests a solution: modifying `APP_ABI` in your `Application.mk`.