# Gradle Build failed - Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

i build my game in unity using gradle mode and I face this error at the end of build.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
```

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':AdColony'.
  >   No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv)

Comment: what is duplicate and how to find.

Comment: Read the top-voted answer in the proposed duplicate: *"Solution: Upgrade android gradle plugin to 3.1 or newer."*