# Problems when building in ionic cordova android

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, building

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information
```

Comment: maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128229/error-no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-llv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your version of cordova-android to the latest 7.1.3 and it will use the gradle plugin for android v3.3 which no longer checks for mips abi in the NDK.

also make sure to set the ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable to the location of your NDK.

Comment: how to set ndk_home in mac os

Comment: add "export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/path/to/your/ndk" to your .bash_profile file in your home directory (/Users/your-user-name/.bash_profile)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I tried many things.
I updated everything I could in Android Studio and SDK Manager. Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin got updated in the process - but this didn't help.
Then I updated cordova (from 8.1.2 to 9.0.0) and cordova-android (to 8.0.0) to latest versions - but this in itself didn't help either.
Only removing and re-adding android platform finally solved the issue:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
npm install cordova-android@latest --save
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform check android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

Did two steps

1.Set ANDROID_HOME_NDK

2.Updated as answered by zbyl

`npm install -g cordova@latest
npm install cordova-android@latest --save
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform check android
ionic cordova platform add android`

And it worked.