# Update Gradle version on Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android

I have updated my Android Studio last night to version 2.0
Then i cannot run app anymore. My Android Studio said that

"This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version"

I already have updated my Gradle to the lastes version but it's don't solve the problem.

Here is my build.gradle.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'.
>
> classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
>
> classpath  'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
>
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

And warrper

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's always recommended to use stable version of Android Gradle Plugin. So,  update your project `build.gradle` from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'` to stable version follows.Then try clean and build let me know aftermath.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

And see [Doug Stevenson's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512622/update-gradle-version-on-android-studio-2-0/36512677#36512677) advice.

Comment: With pleasure & It's my duty. Happy Coding. It's a good practice to read the docs that they give while updating :)

Comment: Where do you know about com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1, I really hate this gradle naming scheme, where do you guys get this info from?

Comment: [Android Plugin for Gradle Revisions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions)

Answer (score 6):

The correct gradle build tools version for Android Studio 2.0 is version 2.0.0:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 stable release and ran into the same issue. Followed all fixes on this questions as well as [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200876) but didn't work for me.

What worked for me was upgrading **gradle to latest 2.12 version** as of today, as well as upgrading the gradle plugin to 2.0.0. Gradle 2.11 didn't work for me.

Also make sure to delete "build" folders.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a "Build > Clean Project" eliminate the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15612484)

Comment: The question was that he can't run any app with a specific error message. I was in the same condition and i solved with the suggested solution.