# Android studio 2.2.3 building error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 2.2.3 and now when I create a new project I get this error:

[image]

I tried all the solutions such as:

- downgrading the gradle
- Edit _JAVA_OPTIONS values to "-Xms2048m"
- dexOptions {
  javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }

**my build.gradle:**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.pdnco.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I also changed the gradle.properties, but still getting this error

Comment: what about `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried, but still no change

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya did it, not working...

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512622/update-gradle-version-on-android-studio-2-0/36512676#36512676) might help u.

Comment: set `buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs' // flatten library directory
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.pdnco.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```