# Android Studio shows inexplicable warnings for build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've created an Android library project in Android Studio and prepared the `build.gradle` to automate deployment to the Maven Central repository, followed the [official instructions](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html) from Sonatype.

Particularly, I've added metadata according the [Metadata Definition and Upload](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html#metadata-definition-and-upload) section

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
     mavenDeployer {
       beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

       //...

       pom.project {
         name 'Example Application'
         description 'A application used as an example on how to set up pushing  its components to the Central Repository.'
         url 'http://www.example.com/example-application'

         scm {
           connection 'scm:svn:http://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
           developerConnection 'scm:svn:https://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
           url 'http://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
         }

         licenses {
           license {
             name 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
             url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
           }
         }

         developers {
           developer {
             id 'manfred'
             name 'Manfred Moser'
             email 'manfred@sonatype.com'
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Android Studio shows warnings like `'name' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'` for the entries

- `pom.project`/`name`,
- `pom.project`/`description`,
- `pom.project`/`licenses`/`license`/`name`,
- `pom.project`/`organization`/`name` and
- `pom.project`/`developers`/`developer`/`name`.

Running `./gradlew --info clean uploadArchives` shows no such warnings. The generated `pom.xml` contains the defined metadata.

These warnings are somewhat annoying, because Android Studio intercepts every commit that includes the `build.gradle` to inform me about the existence of warnings.

**The question:** It there actually a problem with the `build.gradle` or is there something wrong with Android Studio's interpretation? If it is a problem with the `build.gradle`, how do I fix it?

Comment: Could it be related to differing Gradle versions? In that case try using the wrapper like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio