# Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.1.2 I am getting the following error:

> Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above. Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties file or use a Gradle version less than 4.6.

I attempted following the suggestion but this did not fix the issue. Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 711, accepted):

## No need to downgrade!

### Disabling configure on demand requires two steps:

1. Remove `org.gradle.configureondemand` from gradle.properties.
2. In Android Studio,
   **For Mac** go to the `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` and uncheck the configure on demand.
   **For Linux/Windows** go to the `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` and uncheck the configure on demand.

Note, there are 2 `gradle.properties` files

1. In your project `gradle.properties`
2. `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: This has worked, after upgrading android studio and gradle. Setting this org.gradle.configureondemand=false does not work.

Comment: Can you please tell me your exact problem? And what else you've tried to solve it.

Comment: Well, I tried restarting AS, mac, invalidate cache, disabling CoD in AS, disabling it in gradle.properties... 
It keeps showing the same message "Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above"...

Comment: Do not get why Google did not disable the option by default with AS 3.1.2 as they where not supporting it, instead of blocking all the devs.

Comment: The problem was global gradle.properties. In Local one, I tried to override org.gradle.configureondemand=false but somehow it did not work. After editing global ~/.gradle/gradle.properties it works!!!

Comment: i had configured it correctly in the properties files but didn't uncheck it in android studio settings—thanks

Comment: As pointed out by Bozic Gradle **ignores** the setting in the _gradle.properties_ file which is located in the root of the project. I noticed that Gradle accepts the setting when I pass it as a **command line property** as in `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.configureondemand=false tasks`.

Comment: @BozicNebojsa, your comment deserves to be posted as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone encounter a problem when accepted answer's setting doesn't save when you open a second project in new window (even if you unchecked the configure on demand minute ago in this project)?

Comment: @BozicNebojsa right, it's the default behavior. As [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) says:   The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is configured in multiple locations **the last one wins**):  
- gradle.properties in project root directory.  
- gradle.properties in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory.  
- system properties, e.g. when is set on the command line.

Comment: Hey I can't find ${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties. I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Android Studio in another Drive.

Comment: I've set `org.gradle.configureondemand=false` in 1) `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`, 2) `gradle.properties` in the root folder of my project, and 3) `gradle.properties` in the app folder of my project. Still getting this warning when opening the project, so I still have to turn it off in the Android Studio UI. I was hoping by setting the property, this could eliminate this manual step. Note, I did close Android Studio and restart it.

Comment: If you are using Intellij 2018.2.2 (instead of Android Studio), then the option is under "Settings" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Gradle-Android Compiler". Or you can search for "Configure on demand" in the settings search box.

Comment: I could find org.gradle.configureondemand from gradle.properties in local nor global in Step 1. Step 2 did work for me. Many thanks!

Comment: In Android Studio 3.2, I could no longer find the configure on demand checkbox in the `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` section of preferences.

Comment: The preference is now in `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle-Android Compiler` for IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 Please update your answer

Answer (score 47):

In Android Studio, just go to **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler** and click to uncheck the **configure on demand option**, then click Ok and **Sync Project with gradle files** again.

Answer (score 8):

I get same error after update to AS 3.1.2. 
You can still use Gradle version 4.6 but downgrade Android gradle plugin to 3.1.1

EDIT:
just invalidate cache and restart

Comment: maybe you should downgrade plugin gradle version or using gradle default from AS

Comment: Maybe Google shouldn't release broken tools.

Comment: Hi, no need to downgrade anything at all. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990933/configuration-on-demand-is-not-supported-by-the-current-version-of-the-android-g/49994951#49994951)

Answer (score 4):

It is already known bug in Android studio even in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#configuration_on_demand), They have mentioned about this Problem.

The easiest way right now is to disable this feature by going

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.
3. Un check the Configure on demand checkbox.
4. Click Apply or OK.

Check this Image for warning they have provided for specific Gradle plugin versions.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Other 'solution' is use the suggestion by Android Studio. Plugin Android Gradle 3.1.3 and Gradle version 4.4.

[image]

Comment: I like this option more because it doesn't require other developers to change their IDE settings in order to build your project.

Answer (score 4):

From Android Studio **uncheck the configure on demand**:

**Follow below steps:**

1. **For Mac** go to the Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and uncheck the configure on demand.
2. **For Linux/Windows** go to the File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and uncheck the configure on demand.

**Now sync your project**

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

The @wookupmaker answer is correct. But, if it still doesn't work, the problem migh be a **global** gradle.properties.

Even if I tried to override

> org.gradle.configureondemand=false

in my local(project specific) gradle.properties, somehow it did not work.

**After editing global (~/.gradle/gradle.properties) it worked as expected**

Answer (score 3):

Just you need to update Android Gradle Plugin update to 3.2.0-alpha16.

Android Gradle Plugin update 3.2.0-alpha16 instead of 3.1.2

Comment: This looks interesting, but there are two disadvantages: there are already the beta versions available (in other words, the version would have to be changed _much_ more often) and who wants to use an unreleased dependency? But once it's stable, this is the best.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Invalidate cache and restart/disabling configure on demand did not work for me. The only solution that helped me is to import the project from git again.</s>

[UPD] Need to change "com.android.tools.build:gradle" from 3.1.2 to 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do in this case was to use "nuclear function" in Android Studio:

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**.

Like in many other cases, this helped to make Gradle sync and project build working again. I'm using `gradle-4.6-all` and Gradle Plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File->Build,Excution,Deployment->Compiler** and Uncheck Configure on Demand

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Update the gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

**Build > Rebuild Project**

Good Luck

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36040177/5279996)