# Gradle couldn't find org.gradle.configureondemand

Tags: android, gradle

when i try to build android application i get this error:

> Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of 
>   the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6  or
>   above. Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by  setting
>   org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your  gradle.properties file or
>   use a Gradle version less than 4.6.

after adding this line into this file as `gradle.properties` and try to build again, i get error too

```
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6144M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true

android.enableBuildCache=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

Comment: Try restarting your AndroidStudio. Since `org.gradle.daemon` is true, your gradle daemon must be already running.

Comment: @SagarWaghmare not any affect :(

Comment: Sometimes I have to go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler and uncheck the "configure on demand" checkbox once for a project. (The same steps may be necessary again for the next project)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to solve it except unchecking "configure on demand".
Take a look at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994951/6444297).