# Gradle Plugin Update Recommended

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I start the Android code sample "Room & Rx Java (Kotlin)"

[image: if i start Android Studio]

If i click "Update" i get this:

[image: Unexpected Error]

I click "OK" and after build i get this error

[image: Gradel error]

OK maby i use Gradel 4.6. If i search in gradle.properties there is no "org.gradle.configureondemand=false"

Can someone please tell me what goes wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

In `gradle.properties` if it doesn't exist. Then, try to update again. It will override it for if it is exist or not.

---

P.s: There are Two `gradle.properties` files:

1. In your project `gradle.properties`
2. In `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Try to add it inside the second one *(Global one*).

**Check this out too:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994951/4409113

Answer (score 0):

Only change this inside `build.gradle` (Project) file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

And change inside  `gradle-wrapper.properties`(Gradle Version) file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```