# How to handle Configuration on demand not supported error on android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.2.1. I am getting the following error:

> Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the
>   Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above.
>   Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting
>   org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties file or
>   use a Gradle version less than 4.6. Open File

I can easily solve this error in previous version of Android Studio using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994951/8549281).

> go to the File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
>   and uncheck the configure on demand.

But In Android Studio 3.2.1 the configuration on demand check box is not present on above location