# Android studio - Gradle sync failed - groovy-all-2.4.4.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm having the the error below in Android studio v2.1.3 with Gradle v2.14.1 :

```
Gradle sync failed: Cannot find JAR 'groovy-all-2.4.4.jar' required by module 'gradle-core' using classpath or distribution directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio-2.1.3.0\gradle\gradle-2.14.1'
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Updating the gradle version and plugin solved the issue for me by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272475/8383332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete ressources of Gradle 2.14.1 were downloaded from the site :

```
https://gradle.org/gradle-download/
```

Putting them in Gradle directory on Android studio resolved the issue.