# Gradle error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I today update Android Studio it write:  Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2 how can I solve this problem?

Here is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and second build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tosi.ex"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Tue Mar 28 17:26:02 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-all.zip
```

When I changed properties distributionUrl to 3.3-all.zip it stuck in refreshing 
I don't know what to do with this problem. Please help me
Thank you very much

Comment: Try this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254745/4862479

Comment: Another solution is to update your gradle(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio) in android studio

Comment: Try to understand different gradle version first https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034758/5040556

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you need to download the latest version from https://gradle.org/releases
after that go to  file/project structure/project and put the new version in gradle version

Comment: You don't need to go to gradle.org to download. That's what the wrapper is for

Answer (score 85):

#### Updated Answer: For Android Studio 3.1 & above

For **Android Studio 3.1** & above, the `distributionUrl` has been updated to **version 4.6** from **version 4.4**. Your `gradle-wrapper.properties` should look like this:

```
#DATE
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

#### Updated Answer:

For **Android Studio 3.0** & above, the `distributionUrl` has been updated to **version 4.1** from **version 3.3**. Your `gradle-wrapper.properties` should look like this:

```
#DATE
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

#### Original Answer:

```
#DATE
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: When I was a lad we had a thing called Eclipse, it didn't default to broken

Comment: ^ yeah instead Eclipse was itself.. broken.

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you are using default gradle wrapper in  Open File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.

Comment: I accessed this option and was using a local distribution of gradle, changed to the default one. That was indeed the solution, thanks

Comment: I went in there but it's empty; I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 31):

Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Change the version there on `distributionUrl` line

Comment: I update my question. When I change it to 3.3 it stuck in refreshing of gradle.

Comment: You could run `./gradlew clean wrapper` within your project directory from the command line to fix that

Comment: My Flutter project doesn't have that file; it only has gradle.properties, and it doesn't have that distributionUrl line.

Comment: @Pete Then you would need to download Gradle separately

Answer (score 23):

About Android Studio **Gradle plugin version** and Required **Gradle version**, you can see more detailed answer here: [What is real Android Studio Gradle Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839)

For each version of this Gradle plugin, it requires a minimum Gradle version as listed on below table

(Reference page:[gradle-plugin#updating-gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)).

[image]

When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt to also update Gradle to the latest available version.

For example, Android Gradle Plugin version 3.1.0+ requires a minimal gradle version 4.4.

You can be configured via Android Studio **File** -> **Project Structure** -> **Project**. See below:

[image]

Or you can manually modify the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. For example:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

Since this is the first result of google this error, I want to remind that simply click the bottom window error message blue link **"Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project Gradle settings"** will auto fix for you now.

[image]

Comment: I click this and nothing happens.

Comment: Open the gradlew file (which can i.e. be found in react native in the folder for android) with android studio and it will show you the according link.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was missing the `setting.gradle` file.

Answer (score 5):

For Android Studion version 3.3.2

1) I updated the gradle distribution URL to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties file`

2) Within the top-level build.gradle file updated the gradle plugin to version 3.3.2

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Open gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

change it to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have lower version and getting problem importing project with high gradle version and want to run the project without updating gradle than

open your gradle file(Project) and do the small change

```
  dependencies {
           /*Higher Gradle version*/
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'

        /*Add this line and remove the Higher one*/
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
```

**[2.3.3 is stand for your gradle version]**

*in your case change version to 3.2 or 3.2.0 something like that*

Answer (score 3):

- changed distrubutionUrl from 4.1 to 4.4
- changed build gradle version to 3.1.1 under project/android

works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Error Message: Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.9. Current version is 4.1-milestone-1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in SampleProj/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.9-all.zip

I am using Android studio IDE version 3.2 beta 2.

Solution: When we open gradle-wrapper.properties file in IDE it shows correct distributionUrl. but originally it has not been updated. So change the distributionUrl property manually.

Example : open a gradle-wrapper.properties file in notepad or any other editor.
   /Project/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
and change distributionUrl property to like this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

Comment: It has asked me to remove the task clean which already existed. As part of the above Gradle update.

Answer (score 2):

I changes only two points

Obviously they were according to the version of the versions that it has, otherwise they would have to download them

- buil.gradle(Project)

  ```
  dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.toolsg.build:gradle:2.3.2' 
         ..
  }
  ```
- gradle.wrapper.properties

  ...
  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me.
In Android Studio Menu GO to

> File -> Project Structure -> Project.

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update Android Studio and Gradle. Changing the respective updated gradle version in build.gradle file worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with following these 3 steps. I hope, they will work for you.

> Note: I am using **Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1**

0. Click **Sync Gradle**.
1. Go to **Tools** section.
2. Click **AGP Upgrade Assistant...**
3. Click Run selected steps

If it does not work, clean and rebuild or close-open android studio.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also this solution worked to solve these bugs:

1. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found...
2. Add Configuration...
3. Gradle error: Minimum supported Gradle version is...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download the file from here
https://gradle.org/releases

unzip the file and copy folder something like this gradle-3.3(if version is 3.3)
and past it to C:\Android\Android Studio\gradle

Now open the Android Studio and from the left top corner Open File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle

Now give the the path of folder gradle-3.3 in Gradle Home

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue what I did opened project folder and on search option searched for `gradle-wrapper.properties` and edited file to updated version

Answer (score 0):

> Android Gradle dependencies are not working in new update of Android or above Android version 3.2
> Studio

Most important thing if you are face a lot of problems :
It is applicable on plugin 7.1 or new update version
Please Try this:

> Go To -> settings.gradle inside of repositories {  } :

add two files as :

```
maven{ url("https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases/") }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

The complete structure in

> settings.gradle

file as given below :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{ url("https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases/") }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyApp"
include ':app'
```

And last step, it is must be added into gradle.properties files.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Hope so it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Update on 2023 Feb

When you update kotlin gradle verison to '1.8.0'

Open gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

change it to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

- Goto to project setting on top right
- Click project structure
- Select SDK Location then click on Gradle setting
- In Gradle JDK select Embedded JDK jetbrain...
- Click Ok

Answer (score -1):

open the gradlew file with android studio, everything will be downloaded

Answer (score -1):

you need to check and configure your android gradle plugin (in project level build.gradle) and set suitable gradle versino in gradle-wrapper.properties
Cross dependency between two can be find out at
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin