# Gradle Error:Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error while opening project.

```
    Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.5.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>
```

i tried all the SO answers as they mentioned to set classpath like this

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

and distributionUrl like this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and i cleaned project,rebuild and invalidated cache and restarted may times but no luck.i am really not getting what is wrong here but same project running in another System android Studio without any error.
help me to solve this issue.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2

Comment: @sasikumar i tried all those answers

Comment: u can download new Version of gradle 4.1
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710214/how-to-solve-this-in-android-studio-3-0/48710607#48710607

Comment: Click on "Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project". It will download the latest version. Make sure you are connected to an active network.

Comment: @SrikarReddy yes i did that but its not downloading one pop is coming to set the gradle properties

Comment: If you are getting a pop up with options like Update, Don't and Cancel then Click Update.

Comment: @SrikarReddy pop is not of update it is to set the path of graddle

Comment: Setting the path to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1" might work. Unsure.

Comment: @SrikarReddy Thanks man.. It worked.. but why it is not detecting automatically?

Comment: It usually detects automatically, You can see it in 'File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Gradle'. Default selected option is 'Use default gradle wrapper'. You might have a different option selected.