# Android Studio gradle wrong version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Updated Android studio.

Downloaded Gradle. Changed Gradle folder in PC's environmental settings.

In computer, `gradle -version` returns `Gradle 4.4.1`.
[image: Gradle Settings in Android Studio and Environment]

In Android Studio, returns `Gradle 3.5`

*Smart* Android IDE refuses to recognise gradle and I can't compile.

It even gives the **wrong** error message

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.5. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\xxxxxx\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip

[image]

[image: Android Studio Terminal refuses to get gradle 4.4.1]

I have tried restarting, `invalidate and restart`. Nothing works.

How to fix it?

Comment: Use your local gradle distribution setting from your screenshot.

Comment: Tried it before posting here. Still 3.5.

Comment: what is your AndroidStudio Gradle plugin version (in project build.gradle)

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but in the project's `build.gradle`, I only defined `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by restarting the computer.

Restarting the IDE is not good enough. After restarting computer and going into Android Studio's terminal, typing in `gradle -version` shows the correct version. That's when I know it'd work. Sure enough, `gradle` commands now work.

Answered this just to show how *genius* the IDE written by *geniuses* is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to 
`File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle`

Then tick `User local gradle distribution` and set the path to your local gradle

Comment: Tried it before posting here. Does not work. Still 3.5.

Comment: In File->Project Structure->Project what is the Gradle version defined?

Comment: Defined as `4.4.1`.

Comment: Try to remove gradle-wrapper.properties together with what's mentioned above. You don't need it as you're using the local version and not the wrapper. But because of that you can't specify the gradle version (it's gonna use whatever is the local one). I think that why AS use the wrapper as default, to make sure the gradle version is consistent if you change config/there is more than one dev on the project. Alternatively you can still use the wrapper and not the local version and set gradle-wrapper to 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I check android studio offical web, android studio IDE now support version just to gradle-4.1.
I think you can go to gradle-wrapper.properties, and change to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

or

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

, maybe it can solve the problem.

Reference site:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: this is already mentioned by OP. this suggestion doesnt make sense.

Comment: Changing to `4.1` still causes the same error, and in Android Studio's terminal, it's still 3.5, even if I restart.

Comment: Sorry for my last wrong post. Have you try this way, it seem like similar problem... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077785/8355528)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and i had fixed it. first goto https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip  and download it locally. Goto File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle and select "Use local gradle" and set local gradle path that you downloaded just.

[gradle path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNjQ.jpg)