# Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4

Tags: android, exception, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build for the first time on a new Android project but receiving the following build exception:

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4.
```

Other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2) describe fixing this issue, but none of their answers seem appropriate - those items are already set correctly in my project. Furthermore, according to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle), everything in my project is set correctly for plugin v3.3.2.

My `project structure` is such:

[image]

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

I have invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio, problem persists.

**So why is Gradle complaining about v4.4 - where is it getting this**?

Comment: check which gradle is available in your cache folder (C:\Users\XYZ\.gradle\caches). Also share your project build.gradle.