# i am trying to build apk but i get this error in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.7. If usin
  >   g the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in E:\appGoogle\android\gr
  >   adle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this directory :
your project\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

in this file you can update the version ,the lowest version you can use is 4.10.1

My {gradle-wrapper.properties} file syntax:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```