# Android Studio gradle minimum version error

Tags: android, gradle

I am completely new to android studio and I'm referring to the [Android Developers course](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-first-template-project?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-two%3Fhl%3Den%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-first-template-project&hl=en#1) and they mentioned about gradle completing to sync properly and I installed everything properly.

The thing is I'm getting a gradle error every time and I can’t find a fix to it:

`Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 6.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\saketh\AndroidStudioProjects\Sample\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-all.zip Consult IDE log for more details`

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is the same question, and a probable answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2)

Answer (score 0):

There's a gradle.properties file in your project, if you find this (it's easier to find with a CMD + shift + f for "distributionUrl") and change the version number in that URL to 6.5. After changing this make sure you Sync the project again.

Comment: Thanks, but I already got the fix for it. I had to re install android studio and it worked perfectly fine