# The current Gradle version 6.7 is not compatible

Tags: javascript, flutter, asp.net-core, helper, issue-tracking

I have this issue:
The current Gradle version 6.7 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.7.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwwNU.png)

Comment: Search your error before ask a question: possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2

Answer (score 17):

The Solution is to **Upgrade Gradle version**

Try editing the `distributionUrl` in `..\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

[Other gradle versions for future reference](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Answer (score 5):

You can be configure via Android Studio

**File -> Project Structure -> Project.**

Change the **Grandle version to 6.8.3** > Apply > OK