# Error Loading Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

**Problem:** Can't Open my Android Studio version 2.3.3

**Error Log:**

[image]

**What i had done already:**

- deleted the cache on directory

  ```
  ./.AndroidStudio2.3/system/caches
  ```
- restarted my adb
- restarted my PC
- checked android studio plugins for ANKO DSL and AS 2.2 and it is not in my android studio

What i  had done before i sought this issue was that i just updated the gradle version on my app it is saying something the Gradle was somewhat corrupted so i restarted my android studio and now i can't open my Projects even create Projects.

I had these before i can't use my Android Studio 2.3.3

**Messages Gradle Sync Log:**

Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I need to fix this so that i can go on with my projects. Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio) to manually download a supported version of gradle or to regress to your previous gradle version.

Comment: @VivekShankar ive tried it, it didn't resolve my issue

Comment: i was trying to modify my code to Kotlin i guess might be there something happened in intellij plugins

Comment: You could do a new clean install of Android Studio or manually update your `com.android.tools.apk` plug-in (the potentially corrupted plug-in).
Just delete this plug-in and try to start your AS.

Comment: the plugin isnt in the Androiid Studio Setting Plugin

Comment: Yes I know that but gradle tries to build it on start up nevertheless.

Answer (score -1):

u want to enable your all plugin in

go below path and enable all plugin

go to file => setting => plugins => android support plugins enable

Comment: all are enable?

Comment: yeah all are enabled including Kotlin which was one of my suspicion

Comment: than go with this path and in last of pop up window u can see install jetbrains plugins. do it

Comment: Com.android.tools.build.apksig    install this plugin in your studio.