# Could not resolve all task dependencies ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, react-native-navigation

I am using "react-native": "0.59.9". Now I an trying to install the app in windows 10. it getting the below error and I am using react-native-navigation for navigation.

Is this issue due to latest java version

```js
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-navigation was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'RNN.reactNativeVersion' with value 'reactNative57', attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr' with value 'Aar' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 13s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

This is my settinges.gradle

```js
rootProject.name = 'project_1'
include ':react-native-google-signin'
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':react-native-view-shot'
project(':react-native-view-shot').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot/android')
// include ':@react-native-community_toolbar-android'
// project(':@react-native-community_toolbar-android').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/toolbar-android/android')
include ':@react-native-firebase_dynamic-links'
project(':@react-native-firebase_dynamic-links').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links/android')
include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
// include ':react-native-safe-area-context'
// project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android')
// include ':react-native-reanimated'
// project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-localization'
project(':react-native-localization').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-localization/android')
include ':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer'
project(':react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/android')
include ':@leesiongchan_react-native-esc-pos'
project(':@leesiongchan_react-native-esc-pos').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos/android')
include ':react-native-notification-sounds'
project(':react-native-notification-sounds').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-notification-sounds/android')
include ':react-native-image-resizer'
project(':react-native-image-resizer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/android')
include ':react-native-charts-wrapper'
project(':react-native-charts-wrapper').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-charts-wrapper/android')
include ':react-native-razorpay'
project(':react-native-razorpay').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-razorpay/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':react-native-html-to-pdf'
project(':react-native-html-to-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-html-to-pdf/android')
include ':react-native-share'
project(':react-native-share').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-share/android')
include ':react-native-pdf-lib'
project(':react-native-pdf-lib').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-pdf-lib/android')
include ':react-native-google-places'
project(':react-native-google-places').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-places/android')
// include ':react-native-camera'
// project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-pdf'
project(':react-native-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-pdf/android')
include ':rn-fetch-blob'
project(':rn-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android')
include ':@philly25_react-native-paytm'
project(':@philly25_react-native-paytm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@philly25/react-native-paytm/android')
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
include ':react-native-youtube'
project(':react-native-youtube').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-youtube/android')
include ':react-native-camera-kit'
project(':react-native-camera-kit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera-kit/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':amazon-cognito-identity-js'
project(':amazon-cognito-identity-js').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/android')
// include ':react-native-navigation'
// project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/')
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':react-native-splash-screen'   
project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')
include ':react-native-geolocation-service'
project(':react-native-geolocation-service').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-geolocation-service/android')

include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
include ':@react-native-firebase_dynamic-links'
project(':@react-native-firebase_dynamic-links').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links/android')

// include ':react-native-esc-pos'
// project(':react-native-esc-pos').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,   '../node_modules/@leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos/android')
include ':app'
```

Comment: Share your build.gradle file please so we can try to help . and its probably not related to java version.

Comment: hii @George . please have a look at this build.gradle. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ql9e5csJSR0FpYsrhz5QLMLdBbSA6wPR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @george I added my settings.gradle.

Comment: what gradle version are you using ? if its >= 4 , then this is answer will help you , i believe you have the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454202/react-native-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration-of-project-build-only)

Comment: @george I tried the above solution but it was not worked for me