# ./gradlew command line error after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android studio to 3.2, and making the corresponding changes to the gradle version and gradle plugins, I can no longer run ./gradlew from the command line without getting errors.  I can still sync gradle and build the app from the toolbar however.  The error I get is:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated.
  > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.
     > Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70
       Exception Details:
         Location:
           com/android/build/gradle/internal/scope/BuildArtifactsHolder.newArtifact(Lcom/android/build/api/artifact/BuildableArtifact;)Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/scope/BuildArtifactsHolder$BuildableArtifactData; @119: goto
         Reason:
           Error exists in the bytecode
```

Any help in understanding what is going wrong would be really appreciated.  I am using the jdk embedded in Android Studio, and have tried deleting various folders like .gradle, build, .idea and reimporting the project, but nothing seems to fix it.  I am using Kotlin if that is relevant. Not really sure how to go about debugging this.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

relevant portion of project root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha08'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.31"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that while Android Studio comes with an embedded version of jdk, the gradle wrapper doesn't by default use that version of jdk embedded in Android Studio, but instead uses whatever JDK you have installed on your system.  In my case that version was too old, so I just updated it to the latest version of java8 with brew, and my ./gradlew tasks work fine now.
Note: initially brew updated java to java10, which didn't work, so I had to specifically install latest java8.

Answer (score 0):

Try with restarting Android Studio with Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: forgot to mention that I have tried that too, but it didn't help.  I have also tried re-importing the project which didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add gradle to enviroment variables: set PATH=d:\tools\gradle\bin;%PATH%
you can also define a new environment variable called GRADLE_HOME.

Check again the installation steps . 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-install-gradle-2.html

Comment: I already have gradle installed using Homebrew, and am able to access it from the project directory already. I never had a problem with gradle before upgrading the version of Android Studio/Gradle

Comment: Do you have the latest version of gradle also ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: Yes, I have 4.6 installed on my system, and have set the project wrapper properties to 4.5 per the documentation