# How to update gradle version in android when building the project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hi i am updating version code and version number for the release build from gradle using something like this.

```
def versionMajor = 6
def versionMinor = 4
def versionPatch = 3

versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
```

Now i want to know if there is something with which i can update my gradle version to the latest too. I have been hitting internet for quite a few hours for this but not able to find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: I know we can do it manually but i want to know if there is any way to update it when i start the build. I want to automate this

Comment: Till now all i could find is the link which provide us the detail of the latest version in json format
https://services.gradle.org/versions/current