# Gradle and Plugin Update gives Error In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, upgrade

I just Updated the Android Studio from 2.1 to 3.1. The older version of Gradle was working well but slow as it was not compatible with new version of Android Studio. I updated the Gradle(to 4.4) and Plugin(to 3.1) by using the following selected answer;

[How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

But now its giving the following error;

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0. Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.jar
>   Required by:
>       project : Add Google Maven repository and sync project Open File

**Edit:** 
The code in build.gradle is as follow;

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After some downloads its now giving following error while running Configure project:app ;

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred
configuring project ':app'.     at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:666)
    at
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
    at
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at
org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
    at
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
    at
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
    at
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
    at
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find Build Tools revision
27.0.3  at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:176)
    at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:182)
    at
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:885)
    at
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:702)
    at
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
    at
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: Go in `project structure` and change gradle version **`3.4.1` to `4.4`**. AND change Plugin version **`2.3.0` TO `3.0.1`**

Comment: I changed the gradle version to 4.4 and Plugin version to 3.1.3 as both are compatible with Android studio 3.1. But its giving that above problem after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved in such a way:

- update everything pop up at the corner of android studio.
- make sure there is enough space in drive C because some times android studio doesn't gives recommendation for updates if there is less space in drive C even if you are connected to internet.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try "File"->"Invalidate Caches / Restart ..."
2. Try to clean up your `.gradle` and `.idea` directory under your project root directory.
3. Try to add Google Maven repository and sync project

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
           maven {
              url "https://maven.google.com"
           }
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           maven {
              url "https://maven.google.com"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3, you should be sure that your gradle wrapper version is 4.4. Under the root directory of your project, find `gradle-wrapper.properties` and modify it as below.

   ```
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
   ```

Comment: Please mention to not to have allprojects, buildscript, repositories or dependencies tags in '/app/build.gradle'. Then "Correct place of these is to have them in 'ProjecWorkSpacet/build.gradle'".

Comment: Gradle version that is latest is 3.2.1 and wrapper version is radle-4.6-all.zip currently. With this, the error has resurfaced.

Answer (score 1):

Is your project's gradle file similar to that?

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}
```

}

Comment: google is present. I edited the question to include build.gradle.

Comment: Stop using hard binding in your project level gradle:

    `ext {
        minSdkVersion = 14
        targetSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
        // dependencies versions
        supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
        playServicesVersion = '16.0.0'
        versionCode = 12
        versionName = "1.74"
        butterknife = "8.8.1"
        retrofit = "2.2.0"
        okhttp = "3.7.0"
        dragger = "2.12"
    }`

Answer (score 1):

None of these things helped me:

In case you are running a `react-native` setup as me then do the following

1. In the main project folder: `rm -rf node_modules`
2. cd android
3. `./gradlew clean`
4. `./gradlew build`

After a successful build opening Android Studio and running build's work correctly.