# Android Google Maven repository not found

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services

I'm trying to install the google-play-services via android studios sdk-manager. Which says it successfully downloaded them:
[image]

But if Im looking in my android folder there is nothing installed
[image]

Also my `cordova` android is failing because no google-play-service can be found. But even the online look-ups are returning 404 when called. I have no idea how to fix them
[image]

My build.gradle looks the like following[image]

Comment: does your top-level `build.gradle` contains a reference to the `google()` repo or to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` ?

Comment: check my answer to the other similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285271/gradle-and-plugin-update-gives-error-in-android-studio/51300426#51300426

Comment: i added the build.gradle, it seems like i already did what you answered in the other question. my gradle-wrapper.properties also looks fine `distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your top-level build.gradle file has the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
}
```