# I am developing react-native with Visual Studio Code. I have the following problems

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When I'm doing 'react-native run-android' I'll have the following questions

Scanning folders for symlinks in *S:\demoTest\node_modules* (40ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

**Failure:** Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'demoTest'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
  >   Connect to 127.0.0.1:1087 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

[image: Build Gradle - Demo Test]

Comment: did you update your gradle?

Comment: How to update gradle

Comment: 你進Android Studio的 build.gradle如果沒update上面會有一個sync的按鈕.但感覺你有沒link的library之類的.請檢查一下npm並且看一下package.json

Comment: @Harrison please do consider writing in English here so that it can help others too . Thats what this community is for `To Help everyone`.

Comment: @ADM yes I apologize I simply wanted to make things clear and try to be as helpful as possible lest language barriers occur. Again, I apologize

Comment: @Harrison This is mine package.json

{
  "name": "demotest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: @Harrison  My configuration in Android Studio has no problem

Comment: @ChengXi could you add `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` to your project level `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Harrison Yes, it can be added to Android Studio, but it is the same error in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Update the gradle=> File→Settings→Build, Execution, Deployment→Build Tools→Gradle→Use default Gradle wrapper (recommended)

Comment: For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio