# Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available

Tags: android, react-native, vector-icons

hi i have a probleme with testing my react native app, this morning it works fine , but when i test it now i get this error:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
```

> Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-vector-icons
>   could anyone helps me and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is not good at figuring out when there are newer versions of an already used package.
In this case, the version of react-native-vector-icons being referenced in the package.json file uses an older version of gradle.

To fix this, first try:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons -save
```

If this doesn't work, which didn't in my case, go into your `package.json` file and change the package to the latest version yourself.

Get the latest version from the [react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons) website (right now it's 6.1.0) and change the line in the `package.json`, making it:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...

    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",

    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install the newer version of the package

`yarn add react-native-vector-icons`

Comment: I got exactly the same error today and fixed by installation of new version.

Comment: @GammaKo yeah that happened with me too.

Answer (score 2):

Today I got the same problem with you!
And then I try to change the versions, it is fixed now.
just edit your package.json like this.

Before："react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",

After："react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this in your `android/build.gradle` after the `allprojects` section

```
    subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"
                }
                jcenter()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of react-native-vector-icons appear to be referencing a version of the Android Gradle Plugin that recently stopped being available.

Updating your version should fix the problem. You can do this per the react-native-vector-icons [installation instructions](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation) with:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

or if you use yarn:

```
yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your current version of following

1. react-native-vector-icons
2. Current gradle version

This issue is due to that currently your app is being build with different gradle version and the react-native-vector-icons requires the gradle 2.3.+

Installing old version of react-native-vector-icons may fix this issue.

Or update your current gradle version by following this => [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)