# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'

Tags: android, react-native

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
  >   Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
  >    Required by:
  >        project :react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Upgrade to react-native-vector-icons 4.6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native vector icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712552/react-native-vector-icons)

Answer (score 0):

Try below workaround

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try again today as the jCenter services were taken down due to some miscommunication. Now all the packages are restored.