# Android 8.0 - Google API 26 upgrade failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am upgrading my Android App from 21 to 26 due to the new rule, just released by Google. The latest Android App has to support the Google API 26 when publishing to Google Store.

When I change my gradle.build file the compileSdkVersion and the targetSdkVersion to 26, I got bunch of errors. Here is one of them:

> error: SettingNoticeActivity_ is not abstract and does not override abstract method findViewById(int) in HasViews

Please advise what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar and interesting thread [here](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/2001). As suggested by this source please try to:

1. update gradle: you can follow [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35272475/4092588)
2. upgrade the Android plugin: in `build.gradle (Project)` please add:

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
   [...]
   }

If everything has been done properly you can double check the versions in this way: inside the IDE click on `File`->`Project Structure...`->`Project`

[image: Gradle and Android plugin versions check]