# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. On Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle, facebook-unity-sdk

I making a game on unity, I'm using Facebook SDK and FCM SDK, when I building APK it given error as follow

What should I do to fix this issue?

I'm using Mac OSX,

Unity version is 2018.3.11
Facebook SDK version is 7.15.1
FCM Version is 5.6.0

this is build.gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'appcompat-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'cardview-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.cardview-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-api-16.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-16.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-16.3.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-5.6.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-16.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-core-16.0.7', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-17.1.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-17.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-17.4.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-messaging-unity-5.6.0', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'customtabs-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.15.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-applinks', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-common', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-core', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-login', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-marketing', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-messenger', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-places', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'facebook-share', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-compat-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-core-ui-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-core-utils-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-fragment-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-media-compat-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-v4-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'support-vector-drawable-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation project(':Firebase')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId 'com.MarsGames.Poker'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 30
        versionName '1.0.0.29'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'google-services-desktop.json']
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/x86/*.so'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   /Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/OpenJDK/MacOS/bin/java
>   -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.6.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[ D8: Program type already present:
>   android.support.annotation.AnyRes
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
>
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/0.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/1.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/2.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/3.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/6.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/7.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/8.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/9.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/10.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/11.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/12.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/13.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/15.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/16.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/17.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/18.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/19.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/20.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/21.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/22.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/23.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/24.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/25.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/26.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/27.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/28.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/29.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/30.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/31.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/32.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/33.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/34.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/35.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/36.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/37.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/38.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/39.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/40.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/41.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/42.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/43.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/44.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/45.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/46.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/47.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/48.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/49.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/50.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/51.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/52.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/53.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/54.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/55.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/58.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/59.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/60.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/61.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/62.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/63.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/64.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/65.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/66.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/67.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/68.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/69.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/70.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/71.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/72.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/73.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/74.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/75.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/76.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/77.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/78.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/79.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/80.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/81.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/82.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/83.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/84.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/85.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/86.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/87.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/88.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/89.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/90.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/91.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/92.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/93.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/94.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/95.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/96.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/97.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/98.jar,
>   >     /Users/muhammetdemir/Desktop/POKER/Poker_android_2/Temp/gradleOut/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/release/99.jar
>   >     Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   >     https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   >     Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnyRes
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s ] stdout[ :checkReleaseClasspath :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :Firebase:preReleaseBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
>   :Firebase:processReleaseManifest :preReleaseBuild
>   :Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   :Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   :compileReleaseRenderscript :checkReleaseManifest
>   :generateReleaseBuildConfig :prepareLintJar
>   :mainApkListPersistenceRelease :generateReleaseResValues
>   :generateReleaseResources :Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :Firebase:generateReleaseResValues :Firebase:generateReleaseResources
>   :Firebase:packageReleaseResources :mergeReleaseResources
>   :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests :processReleaseManifest
>   :splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease :Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
>   :processReleaseResources :generateReleaseSources
>   :Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig :Firebase:prepareLintJar
>   :Firebase:generateReleaseSources :Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
>   :Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac :Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes
>   NO-SOURCE
>   :Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
>   :javaPreCompileRelease :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac :compileReleaseNdk
>   NO-SOURCE :compileReleaseSources :lintVitalRelease
>   :mergeReleaseShaders :compileReleaseShaders :generateReleaseAssets
>   :Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders :Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
>   :Firebase:generateReleaseAssets :Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
>   :mergeReleaseAssets :transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
>   /Users/muhammetdemir/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/GooglePlay.aar/b7d7e946074fce9450fe78860bafb54d/jars/classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi` was not found, it is
>   required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void
>   com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing$2.run()`
>   /Users/muhammetdemir/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/GooglePlay.aar/b7d7e946074fce9450fe78860bafb54d/jars/classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi` was not found, it is
>   required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void
>   com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing$9.run()`
>   :transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease FAILED 35
>   actionable tasks: 35 executed ] exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   :0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   :0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at
>   :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args,
>   System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String
>   error) (at <df7ba4d130594d168eec372b930522d4>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at
>   :0) Rethrow as
>   GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run
>   (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String
>   workingdir, System.Stri

Comment: Ah yes the infamous gradle build. Have you updated?

Comment: @EvanGertis update what? I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: I've updated question, I added gradle version.

Comment: @EvanGertis I added build.gradle version can you help me?

Comment: I apologize, but that's why I didn't answer the question. I really don't know exactly what the problem is. It looks like it cannot find significant number of dependencies.

Comment: Check your /plugins/ directory (and sub directories) to see if you have any .jar file with multiple versions (eg. audio360-exo28.jar *and* audio360-exo27.jar) if this is the case delete the oldest version

Comment: There is no jar file with multiple versions @remy_rm